# How to create a local user group (in C#)

Tags: c#, local, user-management, usergroups

I'm looking for a way how to programmatically create a local user group. I found plenty of examples on how to query and add users but nothing I can understand about how to create a new group.

```
var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(
                       "WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");

/* Code to test if the group already exists */            

if (!found)
{
    DirectoryEntry grp = dirEntry.Children.Add(groupName, "Group");
    dirEntry.CommitChanges();
}
```

This is what I've arrived at but I know it's wrong as `CommitChanges()` just throws a `NotImplementedException`.

I've been using this as a sample but I can't even get it to work (thanks MS):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms815734

Anyone have a code snippet I can use to create a new local group?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var ad = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
DirectoryEntry newGroup = ad.Children.Add("TestGroup1", "group");
newGroup.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", "Test Group from .NET" });
newGroup.CommitChanges();
```

Adapted from [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306273) article on users.

It looks like you missed the Invoke "Put" in your example - I guess this is why you are seeing the NotImplementedException.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what happened.  I found an example on adding a User and that called "Add".  Same code with "Put" works now.  Thanks!

Comment: Not enough points to vote, but I've accepted your answer.
Thanks again.

Comment: @the-diamond-z - thanks! I realised I didn't upvote your question, so I just have. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: And how to delete a group? Could maybe the "Delete" or "Remove" work? Could I find a documentation of these methods somewhere? Thank you. That'd help a lot!

Comment: Note: DirectoryEntry is disposable.

Answer (score 7):

You may try the following (haven't tried it myself):

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
GroupPrincipal group = new GroupPrincipal(context);
group.Name = model.Name;
group.Save();
```

This uses [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx).

Comment: Why would you post an answer without even trying it?  It's just line noise that leads to wild goose chases.

Comment: You can also pass the group name in the constructor as in:
GroupPrincipal group = new GroupPrincipal(context, "MyLocalGroup")